# Passing ArrayList object as parameter to Copy.copyIn() in CopyManager postgres jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, arraylist

Please, I have an `ArrayList` of entries in memory and I want to insert them into a postgres table using the `CopyManager` jdbc class.
That's the considered code snippet:

```
characters_to_insert_at_once=1000;
CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conn); 
ArrayList<String>requestList;
long record_count = copyManager.copyIn("COPY 
requestListTable(col1,col2,col3,col4,col4)FROM STDIN",requestList,characters_to_insert_at_once);
```

But the above code doesn't work when I pass `requestList` as argument to `CopyManager.copyIn()` as shown above.
Please can anyone tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Does each String in your ArrayList contain a comma separated list of column values?

Comment: Each String in the ArrayList is not separated by comma, the representation of data items in the ArrayList  is the default representation; i.e. : col1 col2 col3 col4 col5, col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 , col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 etc.